# Python sample on Bluemix displays source code instead of HTML output - why?

Tags: python, ibm-cloud

I am trying out Python on Bluemix. To do this I decided to move an example from a book that worked fine on my Windows laptop.  I created the Bluemix example app, then replaced the `index.html` with the html file from the sample and built my directory tree beneath the static directory. The server starts up fine and displays the intro html file as expected, but when I click on a link that should build my html page it displays the page as source code instead of executing it. On Windows this works perfectly. My call to the page looks like this:

```html
<a href="cgi-bin/generate_mypage.py">My data</a>.
```

I have heard that on Linux environments you sometimes need to point out the python executable, but what is the right location of that in a Bluemix environment? Another question would be if the `.py` file is set to executable, but I don't know how you set such a thing in Bluemix.

All help is appreciated.

Comment: Some details such as what you are trying to run would help

Comment: Can you post the contents of your `manifest.yml` are?  Also are you binding your Python app to `VCAP_APP_PORT` to start as well?  Also what is the directory structure of your app?

Comment: What does the `generate_page.py` do?

Comment: applications:
- disk_quota: 1024M
  buildpack: python_buildpack
  host: uffepython
  name: pythontest
  path: .
  domain: eu-gb.mybluemix.net
  instances: 1
  memory: 128M

Comment: That was my manifest.yml. (Basically the same you get with the sample in Bluemix). Under the default from sample static directory I have five directories cgi-bin, data, images, stylesheets, templates. The generate_page.py file dynamically creates an html file from some data. (Note that this page worked fine outside Bluemix)

Comment: Also two important points the python web server starts all right so basically that part calls python correctly. Also index.html must be able to find the page in cgi-bin as the source code is displayed. It just seems it doesn't understand that it should be executed.

Answer (score 2):

You can't directly link to a Python file in a Python webapp.  You should use something like Flask to serve your application.  Flask can do routing for you.

Additionally, in Bluemix and other Platform as a Services' there is only a single binary entry point to your app.  You can't have multiple binary entry points.

See this [example app](https://github.com/IBM-Bluemix/python-hello-world-flask) on how to deploy a Flask app.

Additionally, you can click the button below to directly deploy the example app to Bluemix.

[image: Deploy to Bluemix]

Comment: Thanks for the info Jeff. I can do a direct link on my local computer running a Python webapp I have running there, so that constraint must be for Paas Python Webapps only. The single binary point, does this mean I can't mix static and dynamic web pages in a Paas environment? I will try out your flask sample and see if it can help my problems. Much appreciated

Comment: You need to have one entry point. You need to create Python classes and run from one binary app. This is true really to all cloud based apps.

Comment: Just to clarify this for me, do you mean cloud based apps or web server based apps. Reason I ask as in the environment where this works is on my own computer but I still create the python HttpServer. Hmmm I notice now on the local version I use CGIHTTPRequestHandler when I start my server. Maybe this can solve my problem

Comment: I would highly encourage you to look into a python web framework such as flask.

Comment: @JeffSloyer is too modest to mention it, but he documented this in his blog post [Simple Hello World Python App using Flask](https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/2015/03/30/simple-hello-world-python-app-using-flask/).